# MySQL adding a year over year comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and trying to calculate YoY Sales over different stores with quarterly granularity. Table is as follows

[image]

So far I have:

```
SELECT Store_number, SUM(Sales) AS Sales_q1_2018
FROM table1
WHERE Sale_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY Store_number
ORDER BY Sales_Q1_2018
```

I need to do add a column with the following calculation: (sum(sales q1 2018) - sum(sales q1 2017)) / sum(sales q1 2017)

How can I set different date parameters for a temporary calculation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery for retrive the 2017 q1  join  these to you actual query

```
  SELECT Store_number, SUM(Sales) AS Sales_q1_2018, (SUM(Sales) - Sales_q1_2107)/Sales_q1_2107
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Store_number, SUM(Sales) AS Sales_q1_2107
    FROM table1
    WHERE Sale_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
    GROUP BY Store_number
  ) t2 t2.Store_number = table1.Store_number
  WHERE Sale_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-31'
  GROUP BY Store_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Store_number,
((SUM(IF(year(Sale_date)='2018',Sales,0))
-SUM(IF(year(Sale_date)='2017',Sales,0)))
/SUM(IF(year(Sale_date)='2017',Sales,0))) Q1_2018_vs_2017
FROM table1
WHERE QUARTER(Sale_date)=1 AND YEAR(Sale_date) IN ('2017','2018')
GROUP BY Store_number;
```

[DEMO ON SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54286/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your quarters are calendar quarters, I would write the query as:

```
SELECT Store_number,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Sale_date) = 2017 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) AS Sales_q1_2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Sale_date) = 2018 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) AS Sales_q1_2017,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Sale_date) = 2018 THEN Sales ELSE - Sales END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Sale_date) = 2017 THEN Sales END)
       ) as calculation
FROM table1
WHERE YEAR(Sale_date) IN (2017, 2018) AND
      MONTH(Sale_date) IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY Store_number
ORDER BY Sales_Q1_2018;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54286/3) is the SQL Fiddle.

This is similar to @cdaiga's answer, but with the following important differences:

- Functions such as `YEAR()` return numbers, so the comparisons are to numbers, not strings.
- `CASE` expressions are the ANSI-standard way of including conditional logic in a query.  `IF()` is MySQL-specific.
- The ratio protects against division by `0`.